# Is it possible to force set class name for wayland window in KDE?

Tags: x11, window-manager, wayland, .desktop

I have two Chromium windows. Both are working with ozone wayland. I want both to have different class names. This is for the reason, that I want to apply different window rules for them, and I want to differentiate these two windows by class name.

I saw for such thing, Firefox has a `--class` option, but Chromium does not use it.

In desktop file, there is a field called `StartupWMClass`. Seems it has no effect in Wayland.

Is there a way how I can enforce specific class name (WM_CLASS) for the wayland window in KDE?